# Java 8 + Netbeans 16 throws java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: java.net.URLEncoder.encode(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/nio/charset/Charset;)Ljava/lang/String;

Tags: java, netbeans

I am using Java 8 and NetBeans 16. When I deploy any WAR to Tomcat, then it throws

```
In-place deployment at E:\Web_Project\WebApplication1\build\web
E:\Web_Project\WebApplication1\nbproject\build-impl.xml:1030: 
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: java.net.URLEncoder.encode(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/nio/charset/Charset;)Ljava/lang/String;
    at org.netbeans.modules.tomcat5.deploy.TomcatManagerImpl.createTempContextXml(TomcatManagerImpl.java:361)
    at org.netbeans.modules.tomcat5.deploy.TomcatManagerImpl.initialDeploy(TomcatManagerImpl.java:196)
    at org.netbeans.modules.tomcat5.optional.TomcatIncrementalDeployment.initialDeploy(TomcatIncrementalDeployment.java:126)
    at org.netbeans.modules.j2ee.deployment.impl.TargetServer.deploy(TargetServer.java:670)
    at org.netbeans.modules.j2ee.deployment.devmodules.api.Deployment.deploy(Deployment.java:221)
    at org.netbeans.modules.j2ee.deployment.devmodules.api.Deployment.deploy(Deployment.java:141)
    at org.netbeans.modules.j2ee.ant.Deploy.execute(Deploy.java:86)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor80.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:99)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:350)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:449)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:470)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1391)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1364)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1254)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.module.bridge.impl.BridgeImpl.run(BridgeImpl.java:261)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.module.run.TargetExecutor.run(TargetExecutor.java:573)
    at org.netbeans.core.execution.RunClassThread.doRun(RunClassThread.java:132)
    at org.netbeans.modules.openide.util.GlobalLookup.execute(GlobalLookup.java:45)
    at org.openide.util.lookup.Lookups.executeWith(Lookups.java:278)
    at org.netbeans.core.execution.RunClassThread.run(RunClassThread.java:81)
BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)
```

How is it caused and how can I solve it?

Comment: Please refer: https://github.com/apache/netbeans/issues/5134

Comment: From https://netbeans.apache.org/download/nb16/: _"The Apache NetBeans 16 binary releases require JDK 11+, and officially support running on JDK 11 and JDK 17."_. You cannot use it with Java 8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar issue and I resolved it by downloading an older version of NetBeans, NetBeans 12.0 specifically. I think it has to do something with NetBeans 16 not supporting Java 8 (not completely sure). Hopefully this helps.